# JavaScript commutative behavior for function call. Needed pointers for what exactly happens behind scenes

Tags: javascript, function, commutativity

I have following code and want to check commutative property with impure functions. Can anyone explain why the first two console log print 3, 3 and why the direct function call print 3 and -3?

```js
var multi = 1;
const f = x =>{
    multi = -multi;
    return x * multi;
}

let a = f(2);
let b = f(5);
console.log("a+b:: ",a+b);
console.log("a+b:: ",b+a);
console.log("a+b:: ",f(2) + f(5));
console.log("a+b:: ",f(5) + f(2));
```

Any suggestions/explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the first two logs, you're only invoking the functions twice - in these lines:

```
let a = f(2);
let b = f(5);
```

after which `a` and `b` don't change. 5 + -3 is the same as -3 + 5.

For the last two logs, you invoke the functions four times, and the signs invert each time the function is called, resulting in

```
f(2) + f(5) // -2 + 5
f(5) + f(2) // -5 + 2
```